# Need help identifying 3 handle shower diverter and how to remove it

Tags: plumbing

Can someone please tell me what type of diverter this is and what is the best way to remove/replace it? 
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard purpose designed socket for removing valve stems and diverter stems. It slips over the outer part and engages the wrenching flats on the stem. [Shower valve stem removal socket](https://www.sears.com/master-plumber-247-213-shower-valve-socket-wrench/p-SPM12258408716?plpSellerId=Ami%20Ventures%20Inc&prdNo=1&blockNo=1&blockType=G1)

There are holes to use a screwdriver to turn the socket, but I have found that if the stem is balky what works best is a large Crescent wrench on the outside of the socket held close to the wall.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have a shower valve socket set, but there doesn’t seem to be nut anywhere on this stem. It is flat on two sides and round on the top and bottom.

Comment: Most brands do have a hex shape instead of that clipped circle shape. Doesn't look like a hex socket would fit that properly, gonna have to use some sort of adjustable wrench. As far as identifying the brand, can't help you. I've seen similar looking American Standard cartridges, but only ever hex-shaped.